# Media player with branding

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Please suggest any good media player plugin,Which allows embedding from major video sharing sites, & also allows customization so i can add branding / my own LOGO.

Answer (score 1):

JW player for wordpress is a good plugin for all your needs. Download it from [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend one WordPress Video plugin in your website. This video plugin fulfill all your website needs and include free and premium packages also. You can try free plugin from [WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-flash-player/)